# Fatal Exception in ListView when the phone return to the app after pushing the on/off button

Tags: android, listview, exception, crash

In my app everything seems to work as expected. I have tried to implement all the lifecycle calls. The problem is when I push the on/off button, to get the lock screen, an gets back to the app. This is when it crashes.

The log is:

```
10-26 08:33:23.440: D/OleIPtv_TvChannels_Tv(10331): In the onRestart() event
10-26 08:33:23.475: D/OleIPtv_TvChannels_Tv(10331): In the onStart() event
10-26 08:33:23.600: W/ResourceType(10331): Failure getting entry for 0x7f030019 (t=2 e=25) in package 0 (error -75)
10-26 08:33:23.610: D/AndroidRuntime(10331): Shutting down VM
10-26 08:33:23.610: W/dalvikvm(10331): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412ed2a0)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030019
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1026)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2131)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:865)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:121)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2461)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1336)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1606)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2296)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1644)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1428)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1992)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1813)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4472)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
10-26 08:33:23.700: E/AndroidRuntime(10331):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-26 08:33:33.295: I/Process(10331): Sending signal. PID: 10331 SIG: 9
```

It seems to be caused by the ListView.

My code is:

```
public class Tv extends Activity implements OnErrorListener, OnPreparedListener, OnCompletionListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnInfoListener, SurfaceTextureListener
{
    public static String            MY_PREFS = "OLEIPTV_PREFS";
    public static String            videoindex;
    public static final String      TAG = "OleIPtv_TvChannels_Tv";
    public static final int         MEDIA_INFO_NETWORK_BANDWIDTH = 703;

    private BroadcastReceiver       _broadcastReceiver;
    private final SimpleDateFormat  _sdfWatchTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    // Alerts, ProgressDialogs & Dialogs
    private AlertDialog.Builder     builder;
    private AlertDialog             alerta;
    private ProgressDialog          dialog = null;
    private ProgressDialog          PD;

    // Containers
    private RelativeLayout          moviecontainer;
    private ImageView               myImage;
    private ListView                videoList;

    // Views:
    private View                    mContentView;
    private VideoView               myVideoView;

    // Tasks
    private syncChannels            myTask = null;

    // TextViews
    private TextView                textclock;
    private TextView                textBatteryInfo;
    private TextView                textInfo;
    private TextView                textInfoStreamName;
    private String                  kindofvideo;

    // Strings
    private String                  strStatus;
    private String                  deviceId;
    private String                  addressDB2;
    private String                  readJson = "";
    private String                  successCause;

    // Contexts
    private static Tv               context;

    // Buttons
    private Button                  batteryButton;

    // Booleans
    private boolean                 showingvideo;
    private boolean                 playingvideo;
    private boolean                 playingminimized;
    private boolean                 batteryNotificationReceiverStarted;
    private static boolean          DEBUG = true;

    // Integers
    private int                     streamindex;
    private int                     mode;
    private int                     success;
    private int                     maxstreamcount;

    // Stuff
    private SharedPreferences       prefs;
    private ReadJsonFeed            readfeed;
    private JSONObject              jObject;

    // Handlers
    private Handler                 handler;
    private Handler                 myHandler;

    // Interface Animations
    private Animation               fadeIn;
    private Animation               fadeOut;

    // Utils
    private Vibrate                 vibrate;

    // Arrays, Hash & Lists
    private List<String>            urlImage;
    private List<String>            urlKind;
    private List<String>            urlStream;
    private List<String>            urlName;

    private ArrayList<String>       listMenuNames;
    private ArrayList<Integer>      listMenuPics;

    private JSONArray               jArrayChannels = null;
    private JSONArray               jArrayChannelsNames = null;

    private String[]                from =  { "refchan", "channel", "kind" };
    private int[]                   to   =  { R.id.refnum, R.id.channelName, R.id.channelKind };
    private List<HashMap<String, String>> ChannelsLista;

    // Stuff
    private Typeface                myTypeface;
    private Typeface                myTypeface2;
    private ChannelsList            ChannelsList;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");

        try
        {
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) // Case it's a Lolipop or greater, let's try the imersive mode...
            {
                mContentView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                fullscreen();
            }
            else
            {
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Set the content xml
        setContentView(R.layout.main_tvs);

        // Get the device id number
        deviceId = Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        // Get Saved Shared Preferences
        videoindex      = getString(R.string.shared_video_index);
        mode            = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
        prefs           = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, mode);
        streamindex     = prefs.getInt(videoindex, -1);

        // TextViews
        textInfo        = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textInfo);
        textclock       = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textClock);
        textBatteryInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBatteryInfo);
        textInfoStreamName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textInfoStreamName);

        // Views & buttons
        videoList       = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.channelslist);
        batteryButton   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.batterybutton);

        // Containers
        myVideoView     = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.myVideoView);
        moviecontainer  = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainContainerCenter);
        myImage         = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.myVideoImage);

        // Context
        context         = this;

        vibrate         = (Vibrate) new Vibrate();
        ChannelsList    = (ChannelsList) new ChannelsList();

        // Init Animations
        fadeIn          = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Tv.this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
        fadeOut         = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Tv.this, android.R.anim.fade_out);

        // Init Arrays
        ChannelsLista   = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        urlKind         = new ArrayList<String>();
        urlStream       = new ArrayList<String>();
        urlName         = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Json Server address:
        addressDB2      = ConfigCommon.channelsListAddress + ":" + ConfigCommon.serverport + "/"
                + ConfigCommon.channelListFolder + "/" + ConfigCommon.tvchannelsFile;

        myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/digital7.ttf");
        myTypeface2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Comic Book Bold Italic.otf");

        textInfoStreamName.setTypeface(myTypeface2);
        textInfo.setTypeface(myTypeface2);
        textclock.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        textInfo.setText("");
        textInfoStreamName.setText("");

        // Check if we are connected to Internet...
        checkInternetConnection();

        // Sync channels names / addresses...
        syncTVChannels(); // Sync channels names / addresses...

        // Set the click listner of the channel's ListView
        videoList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng)
            {
                if (checkInternetConnection())
                {
                    myVideoView.stopPlayback();
                    moviecontainer.removeView(myVideoView);
                    moviecontainer.removeView(myImage);
                    moviecontainer.addView(myImage);
                    streamindex = myItemInt;

                    myVideoView.stopPlayback();

                    textInfoStreamName.setText(urlName.get(streamindex).toString());
                    showVideoContainer();

                    kindofvideo = urlKind.get(streamindex);

                    new PlayVideoStream().execute(urlStream.get(streamindex).toString());

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putInt(videoindex, streamindex);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }

        });
    }


    public void onStart()
    {
       super.onStart();
    }


    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        _broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent)
            {
                if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0)
                {
                    textclock.setText(_sdfWatchTime.format(new Date()));
                }
            }
        };

        if (registerReceiver(_broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)) != null)
        {
        }

        if (registerReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)) != null)
        {
            batteryNotificationReceiverStarted = true;
        }

        if (myVideoView.isPlaying() == false)
        {
            try
            {
                myVideoView.resume();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        textclock.setText(_sdfWatchTime.format(new Date()));
    }


    public void onPause()
    {
       super.onPause();

        try
        {
            if (batteryNotificationReceiverStarted)
            {
                unregisterReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver);
                batteryNotificationReceiverStarted = false;
            }

            if (_broadcastReceiver != null)
            {
                unregisterReceiver(_broadcastReceiver);
                _broadcastReceiver = null;
            }

            if (myVideoView.isPlaying())
            {
                myVideoView.pause();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void onStop()
    {
       super.onStop();

        try
        {
            if (batteryNotificationReceiverStarted)
            {
                unregisterReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver);
                batteryNotificationReceiverStarted = false;
            }

            if (_broadcastReceiver != null)
            {
                unregisterReceiver(_broadcastReceiver);
                _broadcastReceiver = null;
            }

            if (myVideoView.isPlaying())
            {
                myVideoView.pause();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public void onDestroy()
    {
       super.onDestroy();

        try
        {
            if (batteryNotificationReceiverStarted)
            {
                unregisterReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver);
                batteryNotificationReceiverStarted = false;
            }

            if (_broadcastReceiver != null)
            {
                unregisterReceiver(_broadcastReceiver);
                _broadcastReceiver = null;
            }

            if (myVideoView.isPlaying())
            {
                myVideoView.stopPlayback();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void onRestart()
    {
        super.onRestart();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        finish();

        super.onBackPressed();
    }


    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
    {
    }


    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
    {
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface)
    {       
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface)
    {
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)
    {
        switch (what)
        {
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent)
    {
    }


    @Override
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height)
    {
    }


    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
    }


    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)
    {
        return false;
    }


    public boolean checkInternetConnection()
    {

        if ((Network.getConnectivityStatus(context) == Config.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false; // Default return
    }



    private void syncTVChannels()
    {
        PD = new ProgressDialog(Tv.this, ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
        PD.setTitle("Aguarde...");
        PD.setMessage("Sincronizando canais...");
        PD.setCancelable(false);
        PD.show();

        if (DEBUG)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Sincronizando os canais...");
        }

        if (myTask != null && myTask.getStatus() != syncChannels.Status.FINISHED)
        {
            myTask.cancel(true);
        }

        String netAddress = addressDB2;

        String parameters[] =
        { netAddress };
        myTask = (syncChannels) new syncChannels().execute(parameters);
    }


    private class syncChannels extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            urlKind.clear();
            urlStream.clear();
            urlName.clear();

            if (DEBUG)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "syncChannels -> onPreExecute()...");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
            if (DEBUG)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "syncChannels -> doInBackground(" + urls[0] + "...");
            }

            try
            {
                readfeed = new ReadJsonFeed();
                readfeed.setAddress(urls[0]);
                readJson = readfeed.readJsonFeed();
            }
            catch (final Exception e1)
            {
                return ("Erro na leitura dos dados Json.\n" + readJson);
            }

            try
            {
                jObject = new JSONObject(readJson.toString());
                success = jObject.getInt("success");
                successCause = jObject.getString("message");
                jArrayChannels = jObject.getJSONArray("channels");
            }
            catch (final Exception e1)
            {
                return ("Erro nos dados Json recebidos.\n" + e1.toString());
            }

            if (success == 1)
            {
                int JsonSize = jArrayChannels.length();

                for (int i = 0; i < JsonSize; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject channelObject = jArrayChannels.getJSONObject(i);

                        urlKind.add(channelObject.getString("kind"));
                        urlStream.add(channelObject.getString("address"));
                        urlName.add(channelObject.getString("name"));

                        System.out.println("Kind: " + urlKind.get(i) + "Address: " + urlStream.get(i) + " Name: " + urlName.get(i));
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error in parsing JSon: " + e.toString());
                    }
                }

                // Get the number of channels
                maxstreamcount = urlStream.size() - 1; // Array index starts in 0.

                // Populate the channel's listview
                for (int i = 0; i < urlName.size(); i++)
                {
                    String channel  = urlName.get(i).toString();
                    String kind     = urlKind.get(i).toString();

                    //String s      = channel.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
                    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hm.clear();
                    hm.put("refchan", "" + (i + 1));
                    hm.put("channel", channel);
                    hm.put("kind", kind);
                    ChannelsLista.add(hm);
                }


            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {           
            try
            {
                PD.dismiss();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try
            {
                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), ChannelsLista, R.layout.childrow, from, to);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation)
                    {
                        if (view.getId() == R.id.refnum)
                        {
                            ((TextView) view).setText(data.toString());
                            return true;
                        }

                        if (view.getId() == R.id.channelName)
                        {
                            ((TextView) view).setText(data.toString());
                            ((TextView) view).setTypeface(myTypeface2);
                            return true;
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });

                videoList.setAdapter(adapter);
                videoList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled()
        {
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


    // Start video play, using a background task so the device is not blocked
    public void startVideoPlay(int index)//String videoToPlay, String videoName)
    {

        myVideoView.stopPlayback();

        textInfoStreamName.setText(urlName.get(streamindex).toString());
        showVideoContainer();

        kindofvideo = urlKind.get(streamindex);

        new PlayVideoStream().execute(urlStream.get(streamindex).toString());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(videoindex, streamindex);
        editor.commit();
    }


    public class PlayVideoStream extends AsyncTask<String, Uri, Void>
    {
        Integer track = 0;

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Tv.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Carregando, Por favor aguarde...");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();

            showingvideo = true;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(final Uri... uri)
        {
            try
            {               
                myVideoView.setVideoURI(uri[0]);
                myVideoView.requestFocus();

                // Play...

            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IllegalStateException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (SecurityException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            System.out.println("onPostExecute");
        }

        protected void onCancelled()
        {
            System.out.println("onCancelled");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            try
            {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(params[0]);
                publishProgress(uri);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainbodycontainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#ff000000"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_frame"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/contentpanel"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/channelslist"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:divider="#ff000000"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer:

I was using only layout-land, layout-large-land and layout-xlarge-land layouts, as my application uses only the landscape view.
The problem was caused because the system, when returning to the app, expect to inflate the child of the ListView first in Portrait mode and there was no portrait instance of the child of the ListView.

I just renamed the above layouts folders to layout, layout-large and layout-xlarge and everything is working ok.